# Jquery only allow one menu item to be expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code from a previous question: http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/4/

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I allow it to still be toggled open and closed, but also make it so if one menu is open and I click to open another menu, it closes the first one, meaning only one menu can be open at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hide the opened `ul` elements first and then `toggle` the current element,

```
 $("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
  $('#filter > li > a').on("click", function (e) {
    var cache = $(this).next('ul');
    $('#filter ul:visible').not(cache).hide();
    cache.toggle();
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/11/)

Comment: The toggle functionality no longer works now though (as in, it wont close if you re-click the same one)

Answer (score 1):

You can hide all the visible submenus before showing the current one as follows

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function(e) {
  var ul = $(this).next('ul');
  $('ul li ul:visible').not(ul).hide();
  ul.toggle();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/9/)

Comment: As the other question, clicking twice on an item no longer toggles

Comment: @balachandran well if you look at your answer, you could see that you copied my fix except the variable name as well as the comment! keep it up.

Comment: @TilwinJoy Oh.. copying.. Err.. I could accomplish his task in different manners rather than this.. And i dont have the necessity to prove that i did not copy from any rep farmers.

Comment: @balachandran 1)there's nothing wrong with this question, i.e it's a valid question. so answering it is not rep farming. 2) there's nothing wrong with asking OP to accept an answer. otherwise the question will remain unanswered forever. You don't understand what is rep farming.

Comment: @TilwinJoy You could have said like "OP, you can accept anyone of the answers here which satisfied your need" But instead of that you said "**PLEASE** accept my answer".. That word just labelled you as a rep farmer..

Comment: @balachandran that is called being polite. have you seen people asking *please share the code..?* or *please explain the problem*?that's how to behave in a community. especially in a community of professionals. I don't know how old you are, but your behavior and the deleted comments were childish.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way. You can also try this:

```
$("ul.opt").addClass("hidden");
$('#filter > li > a').on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).next('ul').toggle();
      $(this).parent().siblings().find('.opt').hide();
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/928Dj/12/)</kbd>

Comment: **best way** Hmm.. i wont agree.. since it is searching up the DOM very much than my answer and the rep farmer's...